# Macbook Pro Retina (Yosemite)でパーティションを追加できない

Tags: macos

新規に購入したMacbook Pro RetinaにBootcamp用にパーティションを追加しようとしています。

Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2014なのでYosemiteがプリインストールされている形です。

ディスクユーティリティからパーティションを追加しようとすると論理ボリュームに関するエラーが発生します。
Bootcampアシスタントからもパーティションの追加は出来ない状態です。

[image: エラー画面]

この状態からパーティションを追加できるようにするには一体どういった方法を取れば良いのでしょうか。

論理パーティションの解除を試みましたが下記のメッセージで失敗しました。

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         999.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *999.4 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 414518DC-72D9-41EB-B349-064AF11EF11E
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
$ diskutil cs revert disk1
Passphrase:
Started CoreStorage operation on disk1 Macintosh HD
Error: -69666: This Core Storage operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group
```

リカバリモードで起動し、ターミナルから同様の操作を試みましたが状況は同じでした。

論理ボリュームのリサイズも試してみましたが、下記の状態です。

```
$ diskutil corestorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 5E5D6F57-0829-4547-8055-DBE97AE46E71
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         999695822848 B (999.7 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume ED872A8F-54CF-4C33-8F0D-B4EF8E6D6021
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999695822848 B (999.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 68D155BF-DCBC-4C58-A4BB-D9528468E7A0
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Conversion Status:       Converting
        Conversion Direction:    forward
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     Yes
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 414518DC-72D9-41EB-B349-064AF11EF11E
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          999376945152 B (999.4 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   Paused
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
$ diskutil corestorage resizeVolume 414518DC-72D9-41EB-B349-064AF11EF11E 700G
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 414518DC-72D9-41EB-B349-064AF11EF11E
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69666: This Core Storage operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group
$ diskutil corestorage resizeVolume 5E5D6F57-0829-4547-8055-DBE97AE46E71 700G
5E5D6F57-0829-4547-8055-DBE97AE46E71 does not appear to be a valid Core Storage Logical Volume UUID or disk
```

ひとつ関連がありそうな所として、FileVaultの暗号化が完了していないらしくこれが操作をブロックしていても不思議はないですね。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もうこの論理ボリューム化されたパーティションには手出しができない状態なのでリカバリモードで起動して再インストールし、FileVaultなどをオフにするという対応を行おうとしました。結果としては再インストールが途中で失敗する状態となりました。。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 現在、こちらのページを見ています。
http://www.macotakara.jp/blog/mac_os_x/entry-25055.html

Comment: 次はこちらを試します。
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157995/unable-to-partition-a-new-macbook-pro

Comment: 起動はどこから行われてますか？昔、iMacで起動ドライブ OS Xディスクのパーティション追加しようとして(パーティションが解除できず)ダメだったことがあります。（その時は復旧DVD作成してそちらから起動したディスクユーティリティで変更しました）

Comment: コマンドRのリカバリモードなので同一のドライブの領域からですね。なるほど別メディアからの起動を試す価値はありますね。

Comment: ただエラーがちがいますからね。`diskutil list`の結果を見るにdisk1はdisk0s2論理ボリュームなのでそのままではパーティション変更できないという事なのかもしれません。  http://www.macotakara.jp/blog/mac_os_x/entry-25055.html

Comment: こちらを見ていても、決着していない感じがします。
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157995/unable-to-partition-a-new-macbook-pro

Comment: yosemite betaの話ですが、こちらは解決したようです。ななめ読みなのですが、FileVaultの利用がなければ…という条件はあるみたいです。 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6479447

Comment: 論理ボリュームを解除して…というのが目につくものの、論理ボリュームなのでそれを縮小して対処する方がいいんでしょうね。corestrageの情報はdiskutil cs list で表示できるみたいです。未検証ですけど、 https://fabianfranke.de/2013/02/25/os-x-corestorage-volume-shrink-and-create-new/ といった形が正しいのだと思います。

Comment: [この質問はトピックスに沿った質問ですか？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @natsukitinyak 開発環境に関する質問ということで、トピックに沿っていると判断したいですが、討議が必要とお考えの場合にはメタへの投稿をお願いいたします。

Comment: これは...軽い Google 検索をしたところ、年末にかけて阿鼻叫喚の様子がみられただけでしたよ、とんだ年の瀬...

Comment: 大変ですね。。。リカバリモードで再インストールする前に、HDD の消去は行ってください。インストーラからみたHDDの状態が既におかしければインストールは失敗するでしょう。

Comment: 復旧メディアから起動したディスクユーティリティからパーティションを削除し、MacOS拡張ジャーナリングの暗号化なしに変更しました。FileVault2を無効に出来たので今後は大丈夫そうです。1パーティション構成にしてからBootcampアシスタントを使い(Yosemite / Win8.1)BootCamp化もうまくいきました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

少し検索したところ、FileVault の進捗がとまったまま、やがてシステムが使用不能になる症状が、Apple の公式フォーラムで多く報告されていました。簡単な解決方法はまだなさそうです。Apple サポートに連絡するのも良いですが、解決はしなさそうです。

Yusuke Ando の付けたログによると、これには、二つ障害が組合わさっていると思われます。

1. FileVault がおかしな状態で止まっている
    `Conversion Status: Converting`
    `Conversion Direction: forward`
2. CoreStorage には、そもそも変更をかけられない

ここで、1を解決しないことには、2を解決しようとしても操作がはじかれると。完全な解決策はないようで、唯一見つかった手順は、 Apple Support フォーラムの[この議論](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6606417)でした。

- `システム設定` > `セキュリティとプライバシ` > `FileVault` で状態確認
- Mac を再起動 <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>押しっぱなしで、リカバリへ
- `Disk Utilities` をクリック
- グレーアウトされたHDDをクリック、トップバーの `Unlock` を選択で、アンロック
- 一番上のファイルを選択、`Turn off Encryption` を選択で解除
- `システム設定` > `セキュリティとプライバシ` > `FileVault` で状態確認
  Decrypt 中の状態もしくは解除可能になっていればよい。

ただ、この手順後、 `Conversion Direction: backward` で止まる人も出ているので、必ず直るとは限らない...

もしうまくいったならば、そこからは、通常のディスク変更ができるようになっていると期待します。flied_onion さんの回答の通り進めれば解決するでしょう。`diskutil cs revert {UUID}` がキーとなるコマンドです。(逆は `diskutil cs convert {UUID}`)

ダメなら、もうこの際、タイムマシンバックアップを取って、ディスクを全消去、OS をインストールし直して、バックアップからファイルを戻していくのはどうでしょうか。厄介な問題ということは明らかで Apple の対応を待ってもいられないでしょうし・・・。私はタイムマシン経由をおすすめします。Apple が対応するまでは、暗号化なしでパーティションをフォーマットするようにすることも忘れてはなりません。

参考: [HOW TO STOP A FAILED FILEVAULT ENCRYPTION (AT LEAST PARTLY)](http://jvr.at/blog/?p=379)

Comment: アンロックまではできましたが、暗号化の解除がグレーアウトされている状態でした。
まだ購入直後で古いラップトップからの移行途中ということもあり、リカバリを賭けてFileValutを無効にしてセットアップしようと思います。

Answer (score 2):

**参考情報**

コメントにも書きましたが、論理グループであることが問題なのかもしれません。

参考までに私のMBP Retina(Mervericks)のdiskutil listのログを書いておきます

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Yusuke Andoさんのマシンでは`/dev/disk1`は`Logical Volume on disk0s2`となっているので、論理ボリュームなのでできないという可能性があります。

---

### 論理ディスクについて

**追記(12/31 18:24)**

調べた情報をまとめると、YosemiteではFile Vault 2が推奨されているので、アップグレードではなくYosemiteがインストールされている様なマシンでは論理ディスク(corestorage)環境にある模様。  
余談ですが手持ちのYosemiteアップグレードのiMacはApple_HFSでした。  
[参考1](http://www.macotakara.jp/blog/mac_os_x/entry-25055.html)

> OS X Yosemiteから、インストール後のセットアップ時に「FileVault 2」の使用が推奨されますが、その関係からか、論理ボリュームがデフォルト化されるようになっています。

corestorageの場合は外側からパーティションの変更はできない(論理ディスクだとどの領域が使われているかは物理ディスクとは異なるので。LinuxのLVMでもそうだった気がします。)。  
[参考2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6479447)

> Your Yosemite partition is a Logical Volume Group or CoreStorage file system. With CoreStorage, you can't resize partitions "outside" of it.

#### 論理ディスクの解除

File Vaultの機能(暗号化など？)が使われていないなら以下のコマンドを通じて解除はできるようです。  
※ 大事なデータがある場合は必ずバックアップしてから実行してください。

diskutil cs revert disk[指定ディスク番号]

([参考1](http://www.macotakara.jp/blog/mac_os_x/entry-25055.html),[参考2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6479447)の質問者の解決コメント)

#### ボリュームとボリュームグループのリサイズ

また、Corestrageのボリュームを増やしたいのであれば以下のコマンドでまずUUIDを確認します。

```
diskutil cs list
```

Logical VolumeとLogical Volume GroupのUUIDを確認します。
Logical Volume Groupに十分な空きがあればLogical VolumeのUUIDは調べる必要はありませんが、
通常Logical Volume Groupが使える容量いっぱいにLogical Volumeが定義されてると思いますので、
新しいボリュームをつくるために既存のボリュームを縮小する必要があります。

以下のコマンドで既存の論理ボリュームのサイズを変更できるようです。  
縮小する論理ボリュームと縮小後のサイズを指定します。

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume <対象のLogical VolumeのUUID> 710G
```

容量が確保できたら以下のコマンドで新しいボリュームの作成が可能なようです。  
新しい論理ボリュームを追加する論理ボリューム **グループ**とフォーマット、名前、サイズを指定します。

```
diskutil cs createvolume <対象のLogical Volume GroupのUUID> jhfs+ cleanOsInstall 45G
```

論理ディスク上ではなく、普通のパーティションを作成したい場合は、論理ボリュームを縮小後に
論理ボリュームグループ、論理ディスクの縮小を行うことで、新しいパーティションを作成するための領域を作れるのではないかと思いますが、ちょっとそこまで調べきれていません。

[参考3](http://blog.fosketts.net/2012/10/03/mac-os-corestorage-resize/) 縮小  
[参考4](http://blog.fosketts.net/2012/10/03/mac-os-corestorage-add/) 作成

～追記 12/31 18：24 はここまで～

---

#### ディスクマウント解除エラーが発生した場合

もう一つコメントに書いた解除できなくて…というエラーが起きたときの画像です。  
(あんまり覚えてないんですけどスマホで撮っているあたり、altキー押しながら起動したディスクユーティリティで起きた気がします。)

[image: ディスクのマウントを解除できませんでした。]

これに関してはエラーメッセージが異なるので、このメッセージがでるようなら参考にしてみてください。

当時参考にしたサイトは[**こちら**](http://zeroalpha0.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-17.html) です。

> ディスクユーリティで、OS Xの入っているパーティションのサイズを変更しようとしたところ、「ディスクのマウントを解除できませんでした」というエラーメッセージが出て、操作を完了させることが出来ませんでした。
>   復旧ディスク（Altキーを押した状態で起動する）からも試したのですが、やはり同様のエラーで変更できません。
>
> いろいろ試した結果、解決方法を見つけたのでお伝えします。
>   一言で言うと、DVDに復旧ディスクを焼いて、そこから起動したディスクユーリティで操作を行うと成功するというものです。

復旧方法を抜粋すると

1. Macを<kbd>option</kbd>キーを押しながら起動し、起動ディスクの選択でいつもの`Macintosh HD` **ではなく** `復旧 10.x`から起動。
2. 左ペインから disk1を選択して、ディスクの作成ボタンでDVDを作成。
3. Macを終了させて、<kbd>c</kbd>キーを押しながら起動(アップルマークが出るまで)。  
   サイトには「DVDは電源ボタン押した直後に入れる」と書いてありますけど吐き出されなければ入れっぱなしでも大丈夫だった気がします。
4. 時間がかかりますが、気長に待ち、そこのディスクユーティリティでパーティションを変更

Comment: 復旧メディアから起動したディスクユーティリティでもパーティションの追加変更のボタン自体がグレーアウトされていました。